# compile a register and create two accounts

Tags: php, sql, registration, forum, invision-power-board

Hello I have a website that has its own registration form and login.
Now I would like to insert a board, such as IP.Board.
only in this way the users will have to register twice, instead you have advice on how I can do to unify the registrations? maybe using the site account and not that of the forum?
I had thought that at the time of account creation, you create two accounts, one on site and one of IP.Board, with the same data and to make them united by ID, you have ideas of how I can do?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: This also strangely looks like a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30306816/1011527).

Comment: ah ... I did not know that my colleague had already asked for help, are days that we are thinking about how to merge your registrations